# TableView Cells Have Their Data Reset On Scrolling

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

**-----EDIT-----**

I've found a workaround to my problem, by utilising the DraggingStarted method inside my TableViewSource. It is not the most optimal solution, and I will continue looking for a proper way to deal with my problem, but for now, I can continue on with my process.

```
public override void DraggingStarted(UIScrollView scrollView)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            GlobalSupport.NewClientData[i] = ((scrollView as UITableView).CellAt(NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(i, 0)).ContentView.Subviews[1] as UITextField).Text;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("hoi");
}
```

in my GetCell method, I then search this new data structure, to find the right value:

```
if (GlobalSupport.NewClientData[indexPath.Row] != "")
{
    cell.cellValue = GlobalSupport.NewClientData[indexPath.Row];
}
```

**-----ENDEDIT-----**

I am working on implementing a TableView-focused App. This means that most of my screens are TableViews, that have re-usable cells in them. These cells are defined using the Xcode Designer (this means I have a .cs, a .xib and a .designer in my resources for each different unique cell).

When building up a TableView with pre-defined data (custom data objects, Dictionaries, Lists, etc.) I call methods in my cell's .cs to modify two UILabels (or a UILabel and a UIImageView) defined in the .xib. This all goes well; the data supplied gets put into the labels and other controls, via the GetCell method inside my TableViewSource, and remains there, even after scrolling (since the data is pre-defined, and uses the IndexPath.Row to determine where to be put).

Now comes the trouble:

I have another cell, that has a UILabel and UITextField in it. The UILabel has its text modified to correspond with my localizable strings file. I have a switch in my GetCell method, inside my TableViewSource, that looks like this:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    CTextInput cell = (CTextInput)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CTextInput.Identifier);

    switch (indexPath.Row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtBSN", "", "");
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtPrefix", "", "");
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtInitials", "", "");
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtFirstName", "", "");
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtLastName", "", "");
            break;
        case 5:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtDateOfBirth", "", "");
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
            break;
        case 6:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtCity", "", "");
            break;
        case 7:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtStreet", "", "");
            break;
        case 8:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtHouseNumber", "", "");
            break;
        case 9:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtZipcode", "", "");
            break;
        case 10:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtCountry", "", "");
            break;
        case 11:
            cell.cellLabel = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtPhonenumber", "", "");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This works great.

Now, when the view's loaded, the user can input his or her data in the UITextField, next to each of these UILabels. Data gets supplied, and as the user progresses down the TableView, all text stays there... Until the user gets to the bottom of the screen, and needs to scroll to view the other cells. What happens then, is that the data supplied in the first few cell's UITextField gets reset to the value, specified in the cell's .xib file, which is "". This is because of the DequeueReusableCell in the beginning of my GetCell method. The GetCell method is being called every time a new cell enters the user's view. This means that all cells that disappear from the user's view, will reset to their default.

[Supply the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ4yJ.png)

[Scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDDLL.png)

[Scrolling back up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/363gA.png)

I don't want a separate set of .cs, .xib and .designer files for each cell in this view, and have found no method to save contents of a cell's UITextField as of yet.
What's more, I need the content of the UITextField inside every cell, in order to create a new object, that I need to further progress this proces.

Any help on this subject is much appreciated. If you need more info, don't hesitate to contact me!

Dear regards,
Björn

Comment: Your cells are not your data model. As data is entered into the cells you need to update your data model and pull the data from the data model when the cell is displayed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate "update your data model"? I'm not sure what a cell's data model is.

Comment: You need to store your data in some other data structure (such as an array or dictionary). Your table cell is just a view of data. Search google for he "model-view-controller" architecture.

Comment: I've found a temporary solution to my problem, as you can see in my original post. However, this seems like a very sloppy solution.

To respond to your comment: I now found a way to get the user input, but there seems like no way to modify the cell's models to apply these new values permenantly. I update the cells, every time now. In the other view, that has two UILabels, I modify the UILabels text via the ViewController. I call a method in the Cell's class and modify the label.Text. But how can I achieve this if I have a TableView with 12 cells that are identical (in structure, not content).

Comment: You need to get the data back from the cell when the text field changes and store this in some variable.  Do this using a delegation pattern.   In your table view cell subclass you can implement the UITextFieldDelegate methods so that you can run code when the text field is changed.  Create a protocol for your view controller to implement and set the view controller as the cell's delegate.  When the text is changed the cell invokes the delegate method in the view controller which updates the variable.  This variable can then be used next time you display that cell

Comment: I see! Thanks for the help. I will try it out tomorrow, and see if this works better than my current solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataSource for your UITableView needs to provide the cell with any data it needs to render fully and correctly. Since cells are reused, they can be thought of as "dumb" and rely completely on the data source to know what to display.

Keeping that in mind, what you need to do is update your DataSource to include whatever is inputted into the UITextField for the cell.

Here is an example of how you could accomplish this:

**1.) Implement your data source for your UITableView to be key/value pairs:**

```
DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string> () {
    { "Label 1", string.Empty },
    { "Label 2", string.Empty },
    ...
    ...
};
```

For your scenario "Label 1" would be `NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtBSN", "", "")`

**2.) Implement your `CTextInput` cell like this:**

```
public partial class CTextInput : UITableViewCell
{
    Action<string, string> OnTextFieldTextChanged;

    public CustomCell ()
    {
    }

    public CustomCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public void SetupCell (string labelText, string value, Action<string, string> onTextFieldTextChanged)
    {
        CellLabel.Text = labelText;
        CellTextField.Text = value;
        OnTextFieldTextChanged = onTextFieldTextChanged;

        CellTextField.EditingDidEnd += HandleEditingDidEnd;
    }

    void HandleEditingDidEnd (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textField = sender as UITextField;
        OnTextFieldTextChanged (CellLabel.Text, textField.Text);
    }

    // clean up
    public override void PrepareForReuse ()
    {
        base.PrepareForReuse ();

        OnTextFieldTextChanged = null;
        CellTextField.EditingDidEnd -= HandleEditingDidEnd;
    }

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            OnTextFieldTextChanged = null;
        }

        base.Dispose (disposing);

    }

}
```

The important things here are the `SetupCell` method and the `HandleEditingDidEnd` event handler. You hook into the EditingDidEnd of the UITextField so that you can invoke the passed in `onTextFieldTextChanged` action.

**3.) Add a `OnTextFieldTextChange` handler and Implement the `GetCell` method in your View Controller like this:**

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("CellIdentifier")  as CTextInput ?? new CTextInput ();

    var labelText = DataSource.Keys.ElementAt (indexPath.Row);
    var textFieldText = DataSource.Values.ElementAt (indexPath.Row);

    cell.SetupCell (labelText, textFieldText, OnTextFieldTextChange);

    return cell;
}


public void OnTextFieldTextChange (string key, string value)
{
    if (DataSource.ContainsKey (key)) {
        DataSource [key] = value;
    }
}
```

Here you define a `OnTextFieldTextChange`method which can be passed in for the `Action<string, string> onTextFieldTextChanged` parameter in the `SetupCell` method that was defined earlier in the `CTextInput` class.

In `OnTextFieldTextChange` method all you do is update the value for the given key in your DataSource.

Now when the UITextField emits an `EditingDidEnd` event, the data source is updated to include the value the user entered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did something along those lines yes. I created a custom Eventargs, that I use when raising an event. I use the Indexpath.Row in my GetCell to bind the cell.ContentView.Subviews[1].ValueChanged, which is the textfield, and throw my custom Eventargs, with which I pass the UITextField back to my controller, and am then able to copy the data, and re-use it in my DataSource, by calling the parent-viewcontroller's property, in which I store the data.